# Can not load less files

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, less

I made a static website in my localhost using bootstrap less and it working fine, But i am getting errors after including it to codeigniter like below image.[image]

here is my all includes in header part.

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js"></script><!--1.11.3-->

<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>less/bootstrap/bootstrap.less"/>

<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>less/my/mynavbar.less"/>

<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>less/my/general.less"/>

<script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>bootstrap/js/less.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

All less files are available as path in particular folders. I don't know why it show me an error like **`can not load less`** . Can somebody guide me to right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely left base url blank need to set your base url I can see it is showing IP in there

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';
```

Codeigniter 3 versions you must set that value.